# Why is the answer of differentiability varying when using first principle and direct differentiation

Tags: derivatives, continuity

Let us consider a function $f(x)$,

$f(x)= x^2\sin(\frac{1}{x})$, when $x\not =0$,
and $f(x)=0$ when $x=0$.

If I use first principle here for $x=0$,LHD=RHD=$0$ and the function comes out to be differentiable at $x=0$.

But if I directly differentiate then

$f'(x)=2x\sin(1/x)-\cos(1/x)$ when $x\not=0$,
$f'(x)=0$ when $x=0$.

Now If I put $x=0$, LHD and RHD come out to be non unique and hence non differentiable.

I am not able to figure out what concept am I missing out on.

PS:This is my first question here so I didnt know much about formatting so sorry for that..

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: https://youtu.be/VAScsSpfKv8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must always trust the definition, which here is the limit of the Newton difference fraction $f'\left(x\right) = \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f\left(x+h\right)-f\left(x\right)}{h}$.

Here we can actually point out the reason why differentiating does not work (however in a more complicated problem we might not have such a luxury and that's why the definition always reigns supreme!).

The reason differentiation does not work is that you are using the $\frac{d f\left(g(x)\right)}{dx} = f'(g(x))g'(x) $ aka the composition rule for calculating the derivative of $\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$, however we know that $g(x) = \frac{1}{x}$ is not continuous at the origin and hence is not differentiable and the composition rule does not work here.

Answer (score 1):

Differentiation as a concept heavily relies on the idea of "local behavior" of a function. This means that a derivative can never depend on a function's value at a single point alone. It always depends on how the function behaves in a small region surrounding that point.

In this case, you are trying to differentiate $f(x)=0$, but the rule that $f'(x)=0$ for $f(x)=a$, where $a$ is some number, relies on the fact that $f(x)=a$ not just at a single point, but on a whole interval. This is not the case for the function you gave: While $f(x)=0$ for $x=0$, it is not the case that $f(x)=0$ on a whole interval surrounding $x=0$, so you can't use direct differentiation.

Answer (score 0):

To verify the differentiability you have to use the definition of differntiability by the limit, since you can't say $f'(0)=0$ because $f(0)=0$. So by the usual proceeding, $$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{(0+h)^2\sin(1/(0+h))-0}{h}=\lim_{h\to 0}h\sin(1/h).$$ Since $|\sin (1/h)|\leq$, we have that $$-\lim_{h \to 0} \vert h \vert \leq \lim_{h \to 0} h \sin(1/h) \leq \lim_{h \to 0} \vert h \vert\implies \lim_{h \to 0} h \sin(1/h)=0,$$ hence $f'(0)=0$. Note that the derivative is not continuous.